# Spark-Sql returns 0 records without repairing hive table

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I'm doing the following:

1. Delete hive partition using `ALTER TABLE ... DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (col='val1')`
2. `hdfs dfs -rm -r path_to_remove`
3. Run ingestion program that creates this partition `(col='val1')` and creates avro files under the HDFS folder`
4. `sqlContext.sql("select count(0) from table1 where col='val1'").show` returns 0 until `MSCK REPAIR TABLE`.

Is it compulsory to do the repair step to see the data again in `spark-sql`? Please advise.

Comment: How ingestion program that creates this partition (col='val1') ? Does it run "alter table" to add partition ? Does data already exist in HDFS directory before running "alter table" ?

Comment: The ingestion program creates the files on HDFS first. then does 

ALTER TABLE ... ADD  PARTITION ( col='val1' )  location 'path_on_hdfs/col=val1'

Answer (score 1):

If it's an external table, yes, you need to repair the table. I don't think you need to do that with managed tables.

SparkSQL reads information from the Hive metastore, and without having information about the partition there, nothing can be counted, by Spark or any other tool that uses the metastore

Comment: Yes. it's an external table based on avro files